# "Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot" greyed out in 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

When I wish to create a **Wi-Fi Hotspot** in 20.04, the option is greyed out.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a long-standing bug.

If you selected **Wi-Fi Settings** from the NetworkManager applet, **Turn on Wi-Fi Hotspot** will be greyed out in the 3-dot menu. In the `Settings` window that opens, just click on **Network** in the left pane, then click on **Wi-Fi** in the left pane, and the **Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot** will then be available.

Comment: The specific bug has this ticket:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/965

Comment: Fixed in Gnome 3.38 ("Orbis").    I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and it still has Gnome 3.36.8.  But this workaround is fine for now (now that I know about it).

Comment: @StephenGornick thanks I was figuring that has to be a bug